# How can I clear the application cache in IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, html5-appcache

In Internet Explorer 10, how can I manually clear the [application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) for a Web page?

Comment: Programmatically or manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing you figured this out, but you can clear cache in IE10 like so:

Tools-> Internet Options -> Settings (in Browsing history section) -> Caches and databases tab

You should see all sites that currently have caches and you can clear them from here as needed. This is what the window looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment, but I would like to point out that Browser Cache & Application Cache are 2 different things. Although, I can't seem to figure out how to clear appcache in IE even after looking at [Microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/).

Comment: You are correct that the Browser cache is different than Application Cache, but my answer above is talking about Application Cache... which is what the question is asking for. Did the method I mentioned not work for you? I just checked in IE11, and it looks like it's still in the same place.

Comment: It looks different than when I last read it. I read it before lunch, perhaps that's why... I just tried it,though, & yes, it does work. Sorry about that. I guess hunger makes funny things happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only clear the application cache without clearing localstorage and indexeddb too (which is advisable if you're just debugging a javascript and have huge indexeddb datastores), I found that you can:

1. clear the "normal" cache, so you don't risk having the browser picking resources from there after page reload, instead of downloading them from the server
2. issue `delete applicationCache` in the console of the Development Tools